# Return SUM SQL Statement, C#, NULL

Tags: c#, sql-server

If the query returns null the goal is to get it to return 0, else return the number. The SUM statement returns the sum of the column values in column `ConcurrentUsers`.

The code below returns a casting error:

> Specified cast is not valid.

It could be because the query is returning a null and is having trouble converting it to int.

Below is the attempt.

Please edit question if anything should be clarified.

SQL query:

```
string query = @"SELECT SUM(CAST(ConcurrentUsers AS INT)) 
                 FROM [website].[db]
                 WHERE(ConcurrencyLicensing NOT LIKE 0)";
```

Return value:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString);         
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

try
{
    conn.Open();
    object userNameObj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if(userNameObj != null)
    {
        int getUserName = (int)userNameObj;
        return getUserName;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the column _ConcurrentUsers_?

Comment: You need to compare it to `DBNull.Value` not `null`.

Comment: Try with `if(userNameObj == DBNull.Value)...`

Comment: it is int. DBNull.Value is the answer, youre right. thanks

Comment: should i leave the question up or delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `COALESCE` ?

```
string query = @"SELECT COALESCE(SUM(CAST(ConcurrentUsers AS INT)), 0) FROM [website].[db]
            WHERE(ConcurrencyLicensing NOT LIKE 0)";
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

> Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL.

Comment: This is also the answer, but the commented answer worked first.